# Convert row-data to sunburst chart data for Highcharts library

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, highcharts, sunburst-diagram

My Row-Data which I got from my MongoDB database. Now, I want to convert the below data to sunburst chart data. Can anyone help me?

> These are my Input data array.

```
[
{
    "globalId": "Chart Global",
    "country": "India",
    "state": "Gujarat",
    "city": "Vadodara",
    "mode": "traffic",
    "value": 2.9
},
{
    "globalId": "Chart Global",
    "first": "India",
    "state": "Rajsthan",
    "city": "Jaipur",
    "mode": "traffic",
    "value": 2.9
},
{
    "globalId": "Chart Global",
    "first": "India",
    "state": "Delhi",
    "city": "Delhi",
    "mode": "traffic",
    "value": 100
},
{
    "globalId": "Chart Global",
    "first": "India",
    "state": "Delhi",
    "city": "Delhi",
    "mode": "population",
    "value": 2000
},
{
    "globalId": "Chart Global",
    "first": "India",
    "state": "Delhi",
    "city": "Delhi",
    "mode": "animals",
    "value": 5
},
{
    "globalId": "Chart Global",
    "first": "India",
    "state": "Delhi",
    "city": "Delhi",
    "mode": "birds",
    "value": 0
},
{
    "globalId": "Chart Global",
    "first": "India",
    "state": "Delhi",
    "city": "Delhi",
    "mode": "trees",
    "value": 0
}
]
```

I want data for the sunburst Chart for highcharts library

Does anyone have solutions?

Comment: Hi @Aakash Limbani, It depends on what exactly you want to show, but in general you need to adapt to the data structure required by Highcharts, for sunburst series it will be like described in docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/sunburst-series You can for example convert the data you provided in this way: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c9xtap61/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a start point you can use this function (I changed a little bit the data to see more effects):

```js
function seqToBurstData(originalData, circleKeys){
    const sunBurstData = [];
    const valuePath2pointId = {}; // auxiliary data used to identify the parent id of a point

    // get all the values for {dataPoint} from top key to {level} key, joined by '_'
    // used to index nameLevel2pointId data, to ensure each point has a unique index value
    const valuePath = (dataPoint, level) =>
        Array.from({length: level}, (_, i) => dataPoint[circleKeys[i]]).join('_');

    circleKeys.forEach(function(key, index){
        const level = index + 1;
        let currentValuePath = null, nValues = 0, sunBurstPoint;
        for(const o of originalData){
            const thisValuePath = valuePath(o, level);
            if(thisValuePath !== currentValuePath){
                currentValuePath = thisValuePath;
                sunBurstPoint = {
                    id: level + '.' + nValues, // scheme similar to Highcharts examples for sunburst
                    parent: level === 1 ? null : valuePath2pointId[valuePath(o, level - 1)],
                    name: o[key],
                    level, // level not required but useful
                    ...(level === circleKeys.length ? {value: o.value} : {}) // only for the final level
                };
                if(level < circleKeys.length){
                    valuePath2pointId[currentValuePath] = sunBurstPoint.id;
                }
                sunBurstData.push(sunBurstPoint);
                nValues++;
            }
            else if(level === circleKeys.length){
                sunBurstPoint.value += o.value;
            }
        }
    });

    return sunBurstData;
}

const originalData = [
    {
        "globalId": "Chart Global",
        "first": "India",
        "state": "Gujarat",
        "city": "Vadodara",
        "mode": "traffic",
        "value": 59
    },
    {
        "globalId": "Chart Global",
        "first": "India",
        "state": "Rajasthan",
        "city": "Jaipur",
        "mode": "traffic",
        "value": 59
    },
    {
        "globalId": "Chart Global",
        "first": "India",
        "state": "Rajasthan",
        "city": "Ranthambore",
        "mode": "tigers",
        "value": 40
    },
    {
        "globalId": "Chart Global",
        "first": "India",
        "state": "Delhi",
        "city": "Delhi",
        "mode": "traffic",
        "value": 100
    },
    {
        "globalId": "Chart Global",
        "first": "India",
        "state": "Delhi",
        "city": "Delhi",
        "mode": "population",
        "value": 200
    },
    {
        "globalId": "Chart Global",
        "first": "India",
        "state": "Delhi",
        "city": "Delhi",
        "mode": "animals",
        "value": 50
    },
    {
        "globalId": "Chart Global",
        "first": "India",
        "state": "Delhi",
        "city": "Delhi",
        "mode": "birds",
        "value": 5
    },
    {
        "globalId": "Chart Global",
        "first": "India",
        "state": "Delhi",
        "city": "Delhi",
        "mode": "trees",
        "value": 5
    }
];


const sunBurstData = seqToBurstData(originalData, ['first', 'state', 'city', 'mode']).
    // add the "intro" key to change the point title according to the level
    map(o=>({...o, intro: o.level === 4 ? 'The value of' : 'Total for'}));

Highcharts.chart('chart', {

    chart: {
        height: '100%'
    },

    title: {
        text: ''
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'sunburst',
        data: sunBurstData,
        name: sunBurstData[0].name,
        allowDrillToNode: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
            format: '{point.name}'
        },
        levels: [{
            level: 1,
            color: 'transparent'
        }, {
            level: 2,
            colorByPoint: true
        }, {
            level: 3,
            colorVariation: {
                key: 'brightness',
                to: 0.3
            }
        }, {
            level: 4,
            colorVariation: {
                key: 'brightness',
                to: -0.3
            }
        }]
    }],

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '',
        pointFormat: '{point.intro} <b>{point.name}</b> is <b>{point.value}</b>'
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/10.3.2/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/sunburst.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```